# Is this PHP function definition wrong?

Tags: php

I've a moodle 3.4 installed on a server and cron fails.
There is a function definition that causes the error (PHP version is 7.0.x):

```
public static function create($time, int $courseid, int $categoryid = null) : calendar_information {// code here}
```

Is this a right syntax or maybe is this a bug? I have no good knowledge on PHP.

This is the error I am getting:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /usr/home/xxx/www/calendar/lib.php on line 1047

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /usr/home/xxx/www/calendar/lib.php on line 1047

Comment: *"I have no good knowledge on PHP. "* - So, why are you dealing with php files then?

Comment: _"PHP version is 7.0.x"_ I'll bet it's not.

Comment: Yeah, the PHP version isn't 7. Use `phpinfo()` to output the version. It's very possible and a common mistake to have multiple versions of PHP on a server - I'd bet your webserver is still using an older version that's installed.

Comment: The current version is PHP 7.0.26

Comment: How have you verified that? You'd only get that error from this code if you're running a PHP 4/5 install. Again, it's possible to have more than one PHP version on a server.

Comment: did you just upgrade from a previous version other than 7 lately?

Comment: phpinfo shows this version number. Moreover, moodle 3.4 doesn't work on lower versions.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: yes last week from 5.6

Comment: Works fine in PHP 7+, only 5 is giving that error: https://3v4l.org/cE9n9

Comment: that could be it then. There stands to be something in a config file still pointing/referencing that older version of php.

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner, I'll check it with my hosting provider.

Comment: _"Moreover, moodle 3.4 doesn't work on lower versions."_ Note that moodle isn't working.

Comment: it is working, @AlexHowansky

Comment: _"I've a moodle 3.4 installed on a server and cron fails"_ I'm confused. Is it working or does it fail?

Comment: There's the Apache PHP module and there is a CLI install of PHP.  cron is using the CLI version.

Comment: which OS is this running off from?

Comment: Right @AbraCadaver. All your comments (from everyone) are so useful. Maybe the cli version is other than 7.0? I'm waiting for my provider answer, then I will post it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `php -v` from command line.

Comment: php -v outputs 7.0.26 too

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The crontab was pointing to the 5.6 version. So when I executed php -v from command line, the outpot was php 7.0.26. But cron process crashed because php was 5.6 version... Now it runs perfectly.
Thanks for your hints, all have been very useful.
Have a nice day!